# Firebase Authentication works but keeps on refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

So I am new to web development and Firebase as well. I have been trying to build a multi page web app in simple javascript and firebase. App looks good and works for most of the part. Yet it is really of no use as I am having following issue :

1. When I sign in through googleAuthProvider (on my index.html page), I am taken to another page which is main.html . Now til here is fine. But once the main.html is loaded, it goes into a loop of continuous refreshing.

My rationale behind this is, that somehow Firebase is trying to re-authenticate the page on loading. And so the loop happens. But why, this I am not able to debug.

I have looked over almost everything I could find on internet but no where I could find a solution which is for simple javascript based multi page web app with firebase.

Here's a link to my app if anyone is interested and kind enough to have a look.

[Chatbot](https://kaushikdev.github.io/ChatBot)

Also, here is my javascript code too.

```js
var config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

//===============================================================================================
$("document").ready(function(){

const signinGoogle = document.getElementById("googleAuth");
const signOut = document.getElementById("signout");
const sendMsg = document.getElementById("send");
const messageBox = document.getElementById("chatBox");
const displayNAME = document.getElementById("dipslayName");
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
 
var currentUser;
var name;
var photoUrl;

 //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
 initApp();
 //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  if(signinGoogle){
   googleAuth.addEventListener('click', e=>{
   firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then(function(result) {  
   // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
     var tokenGoogle = result.credential.accessToken;
     // The signed-in user info.
     var userGoogle = result.user;
     // ...Below line to be rmeooved if not working expectedly.
    // var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   }).catch(function(error) {
     // Handle Errors here.
     var errorCode = error.code;
     var errorMessage = error.message;
     // The email of the user's account used.
     var email = error.email;
     // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
     var credential = error.credential;
     // ...
   });
   });
  
  }
 //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   if(signOut){
          signout.addEventListener('click', e=>{
     
    if(confirm("Do you wish to leave?")){
    promise = firebase.auth().signOut().then(function(){
    window.location = "index.html";
    });
    promise.catch(e => 
          console.log(e.message))
    } 
   
   });
   }
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    function initApp(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    
   if(user){
   window.location = "main.html";
  
   $("document").ready(function(){
    
   currentUser  = firebase.auth().currentUser;
          name  = currentUser.displayName;
   photoUrl = currentUser.photoURL ;
    
   console.log("Current user's name is : "+name);
   console.log("Current user's photoUrl is : "+photoUrl);
         
   displayNAME.innerHTML = "Hi "+name;
   
    //+++++++++++Retrieving Msgs++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    var i=1; 
    var firebaseRetrieveRef = firebase.database().ref().child(name+uid+"/MessageBoard");
    firebaseRetrieveRef.on("child_added", snap =>{
    var retrievedMsg = snap.val();
    console.log("retrieved msgs is : "+retrievedMsg);
    $("#taskList").append("<li id='list"+i+"'><div style='width:100%'><img src='"+photoUrl+"'style='width:10px;height:10px;border-radius:5px;'/><label>"+name+"</label></div><div style='width:100%'><p>"+retrievedMsg+"</p></div></li>");
    i++;
     });
 //+++++++++++Storing Msgs++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  $("#send").on("click", function(){
    var newMessage=messageBox.value;
     if(newMessage==""){
     alert("Empty Message doesn't make any sense, does it?? ");
     }
     else{
     var firebaseStoreRef = firebase.database().ref().child(name+uid+"/MessageBoard");
    firebaseStoreRef.push().set(newMessage);
              messageBox.value="";
     }
   });
 //+++++++++++Clearing/deleting all tasks++++++++++++++++++++++++
  $("#clear").on("click", function(){
     var firebaseDeleteRef  = firebase.database().ref().child(name+uid+"/MessageBoard");
     firebaseDeleteRef.remove();
     $( ".scrolls" ).empty();
     });
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 
   });
                }
  else
  {
  console.log(user+" is not logged in");
  }
  
  });
    } 
     
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

You keep redirecting to main.html.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){     
  if(user){
  window.location = "main.html";
```

You keep redirecting to main.html whenever you determine the user is signed in. Make sure on main.html, you are not using the same logic and redirecting again.

Comment: I do not have any javascript code on my main.html except for a source to my logic.js file and firebase source.                                       
           <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>  <script src="logic.js"></script>   . So, I am still unclear why the loop is happening.

Comment: I fixed this by making the app as single page app. But once again I am facing the same issue. I have multiple html pages in my current app. With google auth, I am able to move to home page from index page, but home page still keeps reloading.